# Confused about #include for seperate directories in C++ using Unix

Tags: c++, linux, unix, header, c-preprocessor

Confused about `#include` for seperate directories in C++ using Unix

Comment: Set the include path properly and #include <library/header>

Comment: _"I don't know how I can check that or find that out."_ Have a look at the makefile used for building.

Comment: Notice: if compiling with `gcc` or `g++`, try passing `-H` to the compiler, it will show the included files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is partially [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77092/1149736), let's assume you're using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) (the same comparison for [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> - `#include <file>`
>     This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file named file in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend directories to this list with the `-I` option (see Invocation).
> - `#include "file"`
>     This variant is used for header files of your own program. It searches for a file named file first in the **directory containing the current file**, then in the quote directories and then the same directories used for `<file>`. You can prepend directories to the list of quote directories with the `-iquote` option.

So when you want to include `geometry.h` using `#include <>` you just have to invoke `gcc` with additional `-I` argument, you just have to decide how "*deep*" do you want to go:

```
gcc -I                               #include
/abs/path/ws/B/inc/Normal            <geometry.h>
/abs/path/ws/B/inc                   <Normal/geometry.h>
/abs/path/ws/B                       <inc/Normal/geometry.h>
/abs/path/ws                         <B/inc/Normal/geometry.h>
/abs/path                            <ws/B/inc/Normal/geometry.h>
```

And if you want to use `#include ""` you may do that too:

Lets assume you're in `/abs/path/ws/A/inc/your_header.h` and want to include `/abs/path/ws/B/inc/Normal/geometry.h`:

```
#include                          path
"geometry.h"                      /abs/path/ws/A/inc/geometry.h
"../geometry.h"                   /abs/path/ws/A/geometry.h
"../../geometry.h"                /abs/path/ws/geometry.h
"../../B/geometry.h"              /abs/path/ws/B/geometry.h
"../../B/inc/geometry.h"          /abs/path/ws/B/inc/geometry.h
"../../B/inc/Normal/geometry.h"   /abs/path/ws/B/inc/Normal/geometry.h
```

If this doesn't work, you are probably in different folder, or have a typo somewhere.

I would personally go with the first solution (you may want to have your libraries "system wide" later and this way you just have to change one `-I` header in makefile without editing sources).

Answer (score -1):

as "PP/linear.h" is seen that means that we are in  "ws/A/me/inc" so with .. we go to "me" with ../.. we go to "A" with ../../.. we go to "ws" then "../../../B/inc/Normal/geometry.h" should bring us to the desired position.